# Android - Layout is giving buttons extra padding; giving me extra gray hairs

Tags: android, layout, button, padding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to completely eliminate padding in a LinearLayout containing buttons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113753/is-there-a-way-to-completely-eliminate-padding-in-a-linearlayout-containing-butt)

[image: http://i158.photobucket.com/albums/t97/fooshards/Whyyyy.png]

What in the world could be giving me this extra ~5-6 pixels of spacing????  It's been driving me mad, I've tried setting the paddings/margins on the parent TableRow, each individual button, the textviews, everything!

Here's the XML layout of what is shown:

```
<TableLayout android:id="@+id/tableLayout1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <TextView android:text="Resource1 - $Price" android:id="@+id/resourceText1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="3"></TextView>
        <Button android:text="@string/buybtn" android:id="@+id/buyButton1" android:onClick="buyButtonClick" android:layout_width="80dip" android:layout_height="36dip"></Button>
        <TextView android:text="XXX" android:id="@+id/resourceHeld1" android:layout_width="30dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center"></TextView>
        <Button android:text="@string/sellbtn" android:id="@+id/sellButton1" android:onClick="sellButtonClick" android:layout_width="80dip" android:layout_height="36dip"></Button>
    </TableRow>

    <View android:layout_height="1dip" android:background="#FF303030"/>

    <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView android:text="Resource2 - $Price" android:id="@+id/resourceText2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="3"></TextView>
        <Button android:text="@string/buybtn" android:id="@+id/buyButton2" android:onClick="buyButtonClick"  android:layout_width="80dip" android:layout_height="36dip"></Button>
        <TextView android:text="XXX" android:id="@+id/resourceHeld2" android:layout_width="30dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center"></TextView>
        <Button android:text="@string/sellbtn" android:id="@+id/sellButton2" android:onClick="sellButtonClick" android:layout_width="80dip" android:layout_height="36dip"></Button>
    </TableRow>

etc etc etc copypasta
```

What chicken do I need to sacrifice to get that padding out of there? In an ideal world, I would nudge the 1dip view up with a margin of 1dip against the bottom of the button.

Answer (score 0):

Because in the buttons you have android:layout_height="36dip"  intead of these android:layout_height="wrap_content" place evrything like android:layout_height="wrap_content"

Hope it helped

Comment: If I change them to wrap_content, it looks like this:  [link](http://i158.photobucket.com/albums/t97/fooshards/Whyyyyyy2.png) -- the little mystery padding on the bottom is still there.

Answer (score -5):

You can also use for spacing for every elements

```
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dip" 
android:layout_marginLRight="20dip" 
android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
```

Comment: why should you downvotiong for my answer??

Comment: idk i cant downvote, im a new user.  anyways thats not really what i asked for help with....

Comment: Hardik, because it's not a good answer.