# Cant vertically center buttons

Tags: android

I have 2 buttons and a TextView inside of a horizontal linear layout. All three views have weights. I have been unsuccessful in centering the two buttons vertically.

I have tried:

```
android:layout_gravity="center"

android:gravity="center"
```

Linear Layout

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#707070"
    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ratioLBButton"
        android:text="LB"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="ratioLBFunction"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ratioKGButton"
        android:text="KG"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="ratioKGFunction"
        />

    <TextView
        android:text="Hello World"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/ratioOutput"
        android:background="#707070"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the parent Layouts that encompass the above views.

```
<ScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#989898"
>
```

This is a screenshot from my tablet. It is the exact same on my android phone.

[image]

Comment: Your code is showing the buttons next to each other. Are you trying to get them on top of each other? While keeping the horizontal bar?

Comment: Or get them centered in the horizontal layout

Comment: next to each other horizontally but centered in the linear layout vertically

Comment: I put your code into android studio and the output looks just like your desired output. Can you give a little more information about what you are seeing

Comment: it looks fine in the preview window. when i run it on my phone and tablet it isnt centered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Positive: I figured it out

Negative: I don't wanna do the fix

[Is there a way to completely eliminate padding in a LinearLayout containing buttons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113753/is-there-a-way-to-completely-eliminate-padding-in-a-linearlayout-containing-butt)

Basically buttons have extra padding at the bottom. It sucks being somewhat OCD. I just want it to line up =(

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `weight` then you need to add `android:weightSum="10"` to the parent, that will help the parent to know what percentage of space it should assign to each each. the weight sum could be value. also all the child of the parent should. use `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` also make all child `android:layout_width="fill_parent"`.

something like this:

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="7">


<Button
    android:id="@+id/ratioLBButton"
    android:text="LB"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:onClick="ratioLBFunction"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/ratioKGButton"
    android:text="KG"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:onClick="ratioKGFunction"
    />

<TextView
    android:text="Hello World"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/ratioOutput"
    android:background="#707070"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="5"
    />
```

the sum of each child weight must be equal to the `weightSum` of the parent. 
Note: the smaller values will occupy more space

Comment: I added a weight sum, in this case 7, to the linear layout and nothing. I also used android:layout_centerInParent="true" and still nothing. The items are spaced horizontally just the way I want them. I need them to be vertically centered in the linear layout.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a silly answer. But did you add `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` in your `<LinearLayout .....>` starting tag? If not please add it. your xml works fine and I could not reproduce the issue.

Comment: I do have that tag. This linearlayout is nested in another one.

Comment: can u also post the parent layout? it does affect how the child layout reacts

Comment: I added the parent layouts

Answer (score 0):

I think your answer lies in the `android:layout_weight` and `android:weightSum`attributes. Both parent and child layouts. Meaning, if you have 3 views with a `layout_weight="1"` inside, it should be `android:weightSum="3"` on your parent as it shows:

**Notice *line:6***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:background="#707070"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ratioLBButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="ratioLBFunction"
        android:text="LB" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ratioKGButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="ratioKGFunction"
        android:text="KG" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ratioOutput"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#707070"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Hello World"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

My preview:

[image]

Comment: My preview shows the same thing, where the buttons are centered. I said that above. That's why I posted a screen shot of my device since that is not centered. And adding android:layout_weight="3" to my layout did nothing =(

Comment: Just did and nothing.

Comment: Well then why not use a RelativeLayout and center_vertical to parent? Have you tried that?

Comment: Rewriting my layout is a lot of work for something this small. Plus I'm still somewhat a beginner. I don't fully understand Relative Layouts. I like Linear Layouts because I know how to use them to make grids which is how I like my UI.